# Atiyah-MacDonald 5.16: Geometric interpretation of Noether normalization lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I am working on the second part of Exercise 5.16 of Atiyah-MacDonald, which involves proving that over an algebraically closed (and thus infinite) field $k$, given an affine algebraic variety $X\in k^n$ with coordinate ring $A=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I(X)$, there is a linear subspace $L$ of $k^n$ and a linear map $k^n\to L$ that takes $X$ onto $L$ (i.e., the restriction to $X$ is still surjective). I am quite confused, and probably am missing some crucial insight/understanding, so this question might not make much sense.

In any case, my approach is as follows: Noether normalization gives algebraically independent elements $y_1,\dots,y_r$ such that $k[y_1,\dots,y_r]\subset A$ is an integral extension. There is a correspondence between points $\gamma=(\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_r)$ of $k^r$ and homomorphisms $p_\gamma:k[y_1,\dots,y_r]\to k$ given by evaluation at $\gamma$. Now Exercise 5.2 (see below) says we can extend $p_\gamma$ to a homomorphism $f:A\to k$. Moreover, both $\ker p_\gamma$ and $\ker f$ are maximal (since they are kernels of maps onto fields), and $\ker f\cap k[y_1,\dots,y_r]=\ker p_\gamma$.

(Exercise 5.2 says that given an integral extension $A\subset B$, any homomorphism from $A$ into an algebraically closed field $k$ can be extended to a homomorphism $B\to k$.)

Supposedly this is enough for the proof, but I have no idea why. Where is the linear map $k^n\to L$ that takes $X$ onto $L$, and how do we know that it's linear? And how does the above prove that this linear map $X\to L$ is surjective?

My best guess is that we somehow think of $\mathrm{Spec}(k[y_1,\dots,y_r])$ as $k^r$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ as $X$, and then the induced map $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to\mathrm{Spec}(k[y_1,\dots,y_r])$ that arises from the inclusion $k[y_1,\dots,y_r]\to A$ is the linear map we want, but I have no clue how to see that this must be "linear"—or even if that idea makes sense for maps between spectra, since they aren't $k$-vector spaces—or how it can be considered a linear map $k^n\to L$, since it is defined only on $X$. And I also have some qualms about thinking of $\mathrm{Spec}(k[y_1,\dots,y_r])$ as $k^r$ since I thought this requires the Nullstellensatz (to guarantee that the maximal ideals in the spectrum are precisely the points in $k^r$), yet we're supposed to use the result of this exercise to *prove* this statement of the Nullstellensatz.

(I have seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339718/consequence-of-the-noether-normalization-lemma) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24794/atiyah-macdonald-exercises-5-16-5-19), and neither one has helped clarify things for me.)